# Custom Validator in laravel with unique check in multiple tables

Tags: laravel-5.3, custom-validators

How to create a custom validator in Laravel 5.3 framework which can check unique in multiple table at the time of insert and update.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would create a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules) that accept the field name and perform query to check if the value is unique.
In this way you have full control over the operations.

Maybe another option, less elegant, could be add multiple times the field to validate and use the `unique` rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

In laravel 4.2

```
Validator::make(Input::all, [ 'url' => 'unique:site1,your_column_name|unique:site2:your_column_name_2']);
```

Laravel 5.*:

```
$this->validate($request,['url' => 'unique:site1,your_column_name|unique:site2:your_column_name_2']);
```

Hopefully it's working fine.

Comment: i want to unify some of the validation and and create a new custom one means like i have 3 tables with same column name slug and i want to check form those 3 table at once and suppose i want to add another table to that list. so I want a way that i will have to add that table name and column name in one place and it will be accessible by lets say "unique_slug"